# Ajax and Wordpress Function Calls not working properly to pull posts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have been trying to work on a function coupled with an ajax call to pull posts based on the id of the link being clicked.  That ID would in turn be the author id, so it would pull posts by that author id.

Below is what I've got set up in my functions.php file:

```
function ajax_filter_posts_scripts() {
  // Enqueue script
  wp_register_script('afp_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/tuts/ajax-filter-posts/ajax-filter-posts.js', false, null, false);
  wp_enqueue_script('afp_script');

  wp_localize_script( 'afp_script', 'afp_vars', array(
        'afp_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'afp_nonce' ), // Create nonce which we later will use to verify AJAX request
        'afp_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
      )
  );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_filter_posts_scripts', 100);

function ajax_filter_get_posts( $talent ) {

  // Verify nonce
  if( !isset( $_POST['afp_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['afp_nonce'], 'afp_nonce' ) )
    die('Permission denied');

  $talent = $_POST['talent'];

  // WP Query
  $args = array(
    'author' => $talent,
    'post_type' => 'roleplays', // Post type
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
  );


  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php else: ?>
    <h2>No posts found</h2>
  <?php endif;

  die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
```

And then the following is my jquery/ajax script:

$('.filter').click( function(event) {

```
// Prevent defualt action - opening tag page
if (event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
} else {
    event.returnValue = false;
}

// Get tag slug from title attirbute
var id = $(this).attr('id');

$('#nexus').fadeOut();

var data = {
    action: 'filter_posts',
    afp_nonce: afp_vars.afp_nonce,
    talent: id,
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
    data: data,
    success: function( data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest ) {

        $('#nexus').html( data.response );
        $('#nexus').fadeIn();
        /*console.log( data );
        console.log( XMLHttpRequest );*/
    },
    error: function( MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        /*console.log( MLHttpRequest );
        console.log( textStatus );
        console.log( errorThrown );*/
        $('#nexus').html( 'No posts found' );
        $('#nexus').fadeIn();
    }
})
```

});

I just can't seem to get any of it to talk to one another, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  I essentially want to be able to click a link, and have it pull posts based on the ID of the link and return them in a listing of posts per my function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you extend your post with the output from both the AJAX request and the "response" you get from your JS? It's basic debugging.

Comment: Why is your Javascript passing the ID in 'taxonomy' while your PHP script is looking in $_POST['author']?

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect some changes I've made; I should note that I'm operating my jQuery in strict mode, which was holding up the function from completing but now I've got it running through.  The problem is, it returns no posts found, but there are several posts in that post type and on the author that I'm using as my test base.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up 2 different DataTypes. In you ajax call you have set the DataType to JSON however the function you're calling is not returning any json but instead outputting HTML.

Try using this ajax function...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
    data: data,
    success: function( data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest ) {

        $('#nexus').append( data );
        $('#nexus').fadeIn();
        console.log( XMLHttpRequest );
    },
    error: function( MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log( textStatus );
        console.log( errorThrown );
        $('#nexus').append( 'No posts found' );
        $('#nexus').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Hope that works

Regards

Dan